# how to use google drive with api server

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-drive-realtime-api

i am trying to get files to google drive

i figure out to use example in to get list of file with 
with "ID clients OAuth 2.0"

once i take the "tokenID" it only work once and i guess that's how it's suppose to work,

i want use the API drive to get files only on my account

so i am going use in Backend server

however there's other type of API authorization for **server**
in console.developers.google and i guess that will be helpful for my idea but don't know how to use it

here's other example i talk about using token

new **update** on the code
i set access offline
Note:
used cookie just for example and testing

the new problem work for the first time then when i refresh again it just show code 
without any result or error

```
<?php

function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}
include_once "templates/base.php";
session_start();
$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$redirect_uri = '{link}';
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
//4/N8jf5YPn4-BwY2J5v30gL5aM-78z2IL7QZMN_TV0odk#
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->setDeveloperKey("{Api server code here}");
if(isset($_COOKIE['code'])||isset($_GET['code']))
{
  if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    setcookie('code',$_GET['code']);
    echo"Saved code";
  }
  echo $_COOKIE['code']."<br/>";
  $refreshToken=$_COOKIE['code'];
  $client->authenticate($refreshToken);
  if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    setcookie('code',$client->getAccessToken());
    echo "New token: ".$_COOKIE['code']."<br/>";
  }
  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

  var_dump(retrieveAllFiles($service));
} else
{

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  echo "<a href='$authUrl'>get code</a>";
}
```

Comment: The "tokenID" you mentioned, are you referring to the "Access Token"? The access token usually expires in an hour.  Are you able to upload a file one time and the next time it fails? what is the code it shows?

Comment: @Gerardo it's supposed to work for one hour ,but right it's only work for one time ,this code show list of files on google drive ,first time with token work,second time i tried with same token it show nothing not even error

Comment: @Gerardo i was missing php error

Answer (score 0):

i figure out my problem
-i didn't notice that my php configuration didn't show error
-i was confuse between code you get in redirect link and "access token" i thought was the same

here's code

```
<?php

function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}
include_once "templates/base.php";
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$redirect_uri = '';
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
  $code=$_GET['code'];
  $client->authenticate($code);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{
  echo " token";
  var_dump($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken(json_decode($_SESSION['access_token'])->refresh_token);
    $_SESSION['access_token']=$client->getAccessToken();
    echo "new token";
    var_dump($_SESSION['access_token']);
  }
  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

  var_dump(retrieveAllFiles($service));
} else
{

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  echo "<a href='$authUrl'>get code</a>";
}
```